# Class Method Not Found (return type defaults to 'id')

Tags: objective-c

I am getting the warning Class method '+getInsuredDOB' not found (return type defaults to 'id') from XCode. I have already declared the method in my .h file. I can't figure out why there is a warning. 
Here is my .h file

```
@interface Sample : NSObject
{
}
+ (NSString*) getInsuredDOB;
```

Here is my .m file

```
@implementation Sample
+ (NSString*) getInsuredDOB 
{   
    return @"Testing";
}

@end
```

Here is where I use the class method and where the warning is.

```
#import "Sample.h"

NSLog(@"DOB is %@",[Sample getInsuredDOB]); //Warning here
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This looks fine to me.

Comment: The code compiles without problems. There must be something else (some typo, import cycle, ...).

Comment: @MartinR Yes, you are right. There is a typo in my actual code. Thank you.

Comment: For future reference, if you have trouble with some code and you post a question here, copy and paste the **actual** code. Too many people post similar code or pseudo code when asking for help. Many times the problem lies with the actual code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code, and once you've compiled it Xcode will accept that the method exists and is valid and the warning will disappear.

Comment: Curious to know how about this statement 'return @"Testing";' in the getInsuredDOB implementation!

Comment: @PremKumar It looks OK to me - what do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: I may be wrong but, How do we say the return type can be of type NSString? He just returns @"Testing"?

Comment: @PremKumar `@"Testing"` is a literal `NSString` object.